# .Net Core Entity Framework Abstraction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface, repository-pattern, dependency-management

I have an **.Net Core Class Library** project which has a context file that uses `Entity Framework`. The context file looks like this;

```
public partial class Qcrr : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<AirWorthyNess> AirWorthyNess { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AwLog> AwLog { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AwserialNumbers> AwserialNumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeInformation> EmployeeInformation { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Password256> Password256 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Persistant> Persistant { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TblApplicationRights> TblApplicationRights { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"my connection string");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        /* my tables
        .
        .
        .

        */
    }
}
```

Now, I also have a simple **.Net Core Console Application** that references the class library **dll** for testing purposes. I want to be able to use the EF DbSet functionality **as it is**, within my console app without having to reference EF again. Of course if I try to use the context file directly, I have the following error;

[image]

Its telling me to reference Entity Framework again.

So my question is, what would be the best practice approach to abstract my dbcontext which lies within my Class Library ?

Would I need to implement the DbContext functionalities (scuh as Add, AddRange, Delete, IQueryable implementations (Select, Where, First...))?

Comment: Is it a .NET Core Console App as well?

Comment: @ceferrari yes, sorry I forgot to add Core there.

Comment: then you need to add "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;". You don't need to install the EF Core package in the console app tho, because it references the class library which already have it and the .NET Core got [Transitive References](https://www.erikheemskerk.nl/transitive-nuget-dependencies-net-core-got-your-back/)

Comment: @ceferrari how do you add a using statement without installing it ?

Comment: If you add the class library as a dependency of the console app, you can achieve that

Comment: @ceferrari I am adding the dll as reference. Adding the project itself does not suit my needs.

Comment: Oh.. In this case you need to install the EF Core package in console app. I can't see another option

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework is already a good abstraction for DB. 
if You add another layer, you always will be forced to add more and more functionality to your abstraction.

Good example is AsNoTracking function for EF. It is good for performance, but adding it's implementation to your abstraction without re-implementing whole EF logic is a big deal. Another example is Spatial data types, raw SQL queries and much more interesting functions that your business logic might require, but you can't use them, because of your abstractions. So don't add another layer.

In my opinion the solution is to use Repository pattern.

Comment: Instead of creating tons of applications that keeps requires me to install EF again and again, I was thinking to use EF in my class library that contains all the DbSets. Then by referencing my dll I would be able to have a nice intelisense vision of my tables and also use the magic of EF itself. Well this was my plan at least.